# Generated source escaped after IFRAME

Tags: html, iframe, escaping

I'm currently looking at a site where all of the generated source appears to be replaced with escape characters after inclusion of an IFRAME. The page being included has no Javascript errors and the code for the IFRAME inclusion is as follows:-

```
 <iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="100%" style="border-width: 0em; height: 1800px; width: 620px;" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" src="[URL to included page[]" id="iframeEvents" />
```

When viewing the generated source everything after the IFRAME has been escaped e.g.

```
&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
```

The original page and the included page both have JQuery running. I've tried Googling this but just get results explaining how to use Javascript to escape from an Iframe.

This issue is present in Firefox, Chrome, Safari (Current Versions) plus IE6, 7 and 8.

Comment: Removing the IFRAME using Firefox's Web Developer toolbar does resolve the issue but I'd like to understand more about why it's occuring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use <iframe .../> but <iframe ...></iframe>.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't spot that! Thanks DuXati.